# Sharepoint 2013 Document Library: Not reflecting Column order from content hub

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-type

In a document library where we have content types for one of the content types we have changed the order of the columns via the content hub settings:
[image]

We republished this content type.

When we add a new document into a document library with this content type however the columns have not re-ordered:

[image]

It has been 3 days now and still the content type hasn't reordered might I be missing something? Also in the **library settings - List Content Type** there is no option to reorder